# Calling .resizable() on an Image makes the image disappear when pulling data from Firestore

Tags: swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Just to give you a bit of context, I'm creating a gallery view that uses the [WaterfallGrid](https://github.com/paololeonardi/WaterfallGrid) library. When I'm using mock data, the gallery looks fine.

```
struct Gallery: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var galleryViewModel = GalleryViewModel()
    
    @State var pictureData = [
        PictureModel(id: "id1", title: "Traditional Clothing", image_uri: "traditional", photographer: "John Doe", body: ""),
        PictureModel(id: "id2", title: "River", image_uri: "mountain_1", photographer: "John Doe", body: ""),
        PictureModel(id: "id3", title: "Boat", image_uri: "mountain_2", photographer: "John Doe", body: "")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            Color("primary")
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Gallery")
                        .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .regular))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                
                WaterfallGrid($pictureData) { $image in

                    NavigationLink(destination: PictureInfo(selectedImage: $image), label: {

                        Image(image.image_uri)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                    })

                }
                .gridStyle(
                    columns: 2
                )
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        galleryViewModel.getGallery()
    }
}
```

[image: Gallery]

But when I do `$galleryViewModel.list` instead of using the mock data, the gallery is empty. When I remove the `.resizable()` call on the `Image`, the picture appears fine.

[image]

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import SwiftUI

class GalleryViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var list = [PictureModel]()
    private let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func getGallery() {
        db.collection("gallery").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("no gallery")
                return
            }
            
            self.list = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                
                let id = queryDocumentSnapshot.documentID
                let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
                let body = data["body"] as? String ?? ""
                let image_uri = data["image_uri"] as? String ?? ""
                let photographer = data["photographer"] as? String ?? ""
                
                return PictureModel(id: id, title: title, image_uri: image_uri, photographer: photographer, body: body)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

[image: Firestore]

Any idea why it's doing this?

Comment: a long shot, you could try using: `Image(image.image_uri).resizable().renderingMode(.original)....`

Comment: it did not work :( thanks for the suggestion tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the WaterfallGrid library rather than my code here. If there are less than 3 elements, it does not display anything. There is an Issue created on the [Github](https://github.com/paololeonardi/WaterfallGrid/issues/53) page.

Adding `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` inside the WaterfallGrid fixed it for me.